# Как правильно настроить .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть две задачи:

1. Перенаправлять главную страницу сайта `http://site.ru` в директорию `feed` (т.е. `http://site.ru/feed/`). Реализовано это на сайте в `.htaccess` так:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/ [L,R=301]
   ```
2. Необходимо автоматически из ссылки `http://site.ru/feed/` убрать текст `feed/` так, чтобы загрузка все так же происходила из папки `feed/`. Ссылка визуально должна выглядеть: `http://site.ru`

Подскажите, что дописать в `.htaccess`

Comment: А изначально нельзя установить ROOT директорию сайта там где надо?

Comment: Дело в том, что на сайте установлено два движка, между собой они не конфликтуют только если второй лежит в поддиректории (в данном случае это feed). Но загружаться индексная страница сайта должна перенаправлением в директорию feed на файл index.php. Только нужно визуально убрать из ссылки текст feed/

Comment: @NoName, Посмотрите мой ответ тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451894/%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url#451898 (UPD2)

Answer (score 1):

Если только главную страницу, то так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/$1 [L]
```

Если вообще все перенаправить на `/feed/`, то так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/$1 [L]
```

При этом по адресу `http://site.ru/feed/` все равно будет открываться так же директория `feed` и от этого не избавиться, т.к. если на этот запрос поставить редирект, то будет бесконечная переадресация. Тут уже надо менять путь в веб директории

Answer (score 0):

Давно уже не работал с .htaccess. Если я правильно понял вопрос, то насколько я помню, достаточно вроде убрать просто флаг R для внутреннего редиректа.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/ [L]
```

Comment: Да, и, вероятно, добавить, что именно перенаправлять: `^(.*)$ /feed/$1 [L]`. Удивляюсь, почему вы даете ответ, не убедившись в его правильности.

Comment: Да, согласен, это будет более корректно. Но только в том случае, если задача стоит в перенаправлении именно всех ссылок, а не только главной (в примере автора этого явно не указано, хотя, думаю, и подразумевается)

Comment: Ссылка http://site.ru/ все также превращается в http://site.ru/feed/, а мне необходимо визуально "почистить" ссылку от слова feed без потери переадресации.

Comment: @NoName, `^(/)$` замените на `^\/?$`.

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает (feed остается)

Comment: @NoName, при каком виде ссылки `feed` остается?

Comment: и так RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/)$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/ [L], и вот так RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /feed/ [L]

Comment: @NoName, я не про правило спрашиваю, а про ссылку, которую вы в строке браузера набрали, при которой `feed` в ней остается, а его там быть не должно!?