# Убрать название папки из url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть сайт и в папке page лежат основные страницы

www.site.com/page/stranica.php

Создаю `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Загружаю в корень и ничего не происходит. Где я ошибся, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Если файл есть в наличии, то правила переадресации на него не распространяются. Кажется так.

Comment: Не очень понял "файл есть в наличии",если Вас не затруднит,можете подробнее пояснить

Comment: `www.site.com/page/stranica.php` - файл реально существует в папке `page`? Если да, то переадресация для него не будет срабатывать. Вы наберите у себя в браузере `www.site.com/page/stranicaNOPAGE.php` и посмотрите что будет.

Comment: 404 ошибка,страница не существует

Comment: а `page` из url исчезла?

Comment: нет,так с page и есть

Comment: Что-то я вас тогда в заблуждение что ли ввел. Тестировал недавно, переадресация не срабатывала на существующих файлах О_о

Comment: просто первый раз с эти сталкиваюсь,может еще какие строчки настройки нужны в htaccess

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вам требуется экранировать слеш, чтобы регулярное выражение работало

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPD**

`RewriteEngine On` - включает обработку правил переадресации в `.htaccess`.

**UPD2**

Создал такую конструкцию

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# включаем обработку переадресаций
 RewriteEngine On

# проверка переменной в параметрах запроса для отмены зацикливание переадресации
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stopredirect=STOPREDIRECT
# проверка, что файл к которому обратились существует на сервере
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# проверка, что обратились к файлу в папке page
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/page\/(.+)$
# 301 редирект на файл в корне сайта
 RewriteRule .* /%1 [R=301,L]

# так как файла в корне сайта нет, нужно открыть файл из папки page не меняя url
# проверка, что обратились к файлу в корне сайта
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([^\/]+)$
# проверка, что такой файл есть в папке page
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}page%{REQUEST_URI} -f
# открываем файл из папки page (дописывая параметр stopredirect в запрос для отмены зацикливания)
 RewriteRule .* /page%{REQUEST_URI}?stopredirect=STOPREDIRECT&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

1. **Работает при обращении к реально существующим файлам** лежащим в папке `page`. При этом из url в адресной строке браузера удаляется `page/` (301 редирект). Если файла в папке `page` нет, смена url в адресной строке браузера не происходит, выводится 404 ошибка.
2. При обращении к файлу в корне сайта с именем реально существующего файла в папке `page`, запускается файл из папки `page`.

Comment: Все равно нет,а в файле htaccess должно быть еще что нибудь?У меня просто одна эта строка

Comment: @zkolya, обновил ответ.

Comment: Теперь он действительно убирает page ,но пишет 404 ошибку

Comment: @zkolya, у вас файлы-то существует в корневой директории на которые переадресация идет?

Comment: Цель такая,файлы лежат в page. мне нужно чтоб с url это убралось

Comment: @zkolya, смотрите upd2 в моем ответе.

Comment: Все равно  404,хотя файлы лежат в page

Comment: @zkolya, покажите, что набираете в адресной строке браузера и что в этой строке отображается при выводе 404 ошибки? + скажите какая версия Apache у вас?

Comment: я просто перехожу по ссылке site.com/page/page.php и хочу попасть на эту страницу в этой папке,но в url ,без page

Comment: @zkolya, вы сговорились что ли все толком не отвечать на уточняющие вопросы? 1. Файл `site.com/page/page.php` существует физически на вашем сайте? 2. Что отображается в адресной строке при выводе 404 ошибки? 3. Нет ли уточняющей информации о файле в тексте 404 ошибки? Если есть, то тоже покажите ее.

Comment: да он есть физически,вот какая ошибка 404: файл не существует

При запросе страницы с сайта нашего пользователя произошла ошибка 404.

Запрашиваемый файл не найден.

Проверьте правильность ввода URL.

Comment: @zkolya, на вопрос под цифрой 2 не ответили.

Comment: site.com/page.php

Comment: @zkolya,  перед этой строкой `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}page%{REQUEST_URI} -f` поставьте решетку `#`. Что получиться? Если начнет работать, то попробуйте заменить ее на `RewriteCond /page%{REQUEST_URI} -f`.

Comment: ,так 500: внутренняя ошибка сервера

При запросе страницы с сайта нашего пользователя произошла ошибка.

Свяжитесь с вебмастером сайта.

Comment: @zkolya, если вы заменили строку `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}page%{REQUEST_URI} -f` на `#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}page%{REQUEST_URI} -f` то такой ошибки не может быть. Только что протестировал.

Comment: @zkolya, в общем плюньте на это дело. Напишите роутер в `php` и пусть он обрабатывает входящие запросы.

Comment: Что за роутер,можно поподробнее

Comment: @zkolya, это когда человеко-понятные урлы как на этом сайте. `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451894/Убрать-название-папки-из-url/` запрос идет не на этот файл, а например на `index.php`, где уже скрипт на `php` разбирает строку из url и в зависимости от правил запускает тот или иной скрипт. Гугл https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BB Этот принцип можно применить и для реальных файлов.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/page/$1 -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Все ссылки на stranica.php должны выглядеть так:

```
<а href="stranica.php" title="">страница
```

а не так:

```
<а href="page/stranica.php" title="">страница
```