# Замена части URL .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылки вида

```
ex-film.com/pages/registration.php
ex-film.com/pages/films.php
```

надо заменить на ссылки такого вида

```
ex-film.com/registration.php 
ex-film.com/films.php
```

Написал такой .htaccess, но не работает

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$1 /pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451894/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url/451898#451898 писал свой ответ, у ТС не заработало, хотя на localhost'е работает отлично.

Comment: Мне вот любопытно, зачем вы включили mod_rewrite, но у ссылок вы хотите оставить `.php` в конце? Сделайте хоть какой-то минимальный роутинг средствами PHP и направляйте запросы туда

Comment: @tutankhamun: Возможно, ТС использует CMS, а там подобных нештяков не завезли. Потому лупят реврайты и даже apache под nginx ставят ради такого сомнительного удовольствия.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^registration.php /pages/registration.php  [L,QSA]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^films.php /pages/films.php  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Наоброт, необходимо избавиться от `pages`.

Comment: Так мы и избавляемся от pages.

Comment: Проверьте [ваше правило](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/). Вот так надо: `RewriteRule ^pages\/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: PoGis, так нечего не меняет, @romeo пишет "Object not found!"